# Sort a list and all its nested objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

There is an organisation with several departments and each department has a few employees.

I have created the following object model:

```
public class Organisation
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have a list of these organisations and using LINQ, I would like to sort/order the output as follows:

1) Organisations: Ordered by Code and Name

2) Departments:   Ordered by Code and Name

3) Employees:     Ordered by Code and Name

Below is some test data that I have populated:

```
var britishTelecomLtd = new Organisation
            {
                Code = 8,
                Name = "British Telecom Ltd",
                Type = "Institutional",
                Departments =  new List<Department>
                    {
                        new Department
                            {
                                Code = 6,
                                Name = "Finance",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 5,
                                                Name = "Peter"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 2,
                                                Name = "James"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 6,
                                                Name = "Andrew"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            new Department
                            {
                                Code = 5,
                                Name = "Accounts",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 15,
                                                Name = "Jane"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 22,
                                                Name = "John"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 16,
                                                Name = "Mark"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                    } 

            };

        var virginMediaLtd = new Organisation
        {
            Code = 5,
            Name = "Virgin Media Ltd",
            Type = "Institutional",
            Departments = new List<Department>
                    {
                        new Department
                            {
                                Code = 6,
                                Name = "Sales",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                       new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 5,
                                                Name = "Peter"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 2,
                                                Name = "James"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 6,
                                                Name = "Andrew"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            new Department
                            {
                                Code = 5,
                                Name = "Support",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 15,
                                                Name = "Jane"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 22,
                                                Name = "John"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 16,
                                                Name = "Mark"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                    }

        };

        var pcWorldLtd = new Organisation
        {
            Code = 18,
            Name = "PC World Ltd",
            Type = "Retail",
            Departments = new List<Department>
                    {
                        new Department
                            {
                                Code = 6,
                                Name = "Marketing",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                          new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 15,
                                                Name = "Jane"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 22,
                                                Name = "John"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 16,
                                                Name = "Mark"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                            new Department
                            {
                                Code = 5,
                                Name = "Customer Services",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                         new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 5,
                                                Name = "Kelly"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 2,
                                                Name = "Jenny"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 6,
                                                Name = "Tricia"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                    }

        };

        var blueCatLtd = new Organisation
            {
                Code = 3,
                Name = "Blue Cat Music Ltd",
                Type = "Retail",
                Departments = new List<Department>
                    {
                        new Department
                            {
                                Code = 6,
                                Name = "Sales",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                         new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 5,
                                                Name = "Peter"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 2,
                                                Name = "James"
                                            },
                                            new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 6,
                                                Name = "Andrew"
                                            }
                                    }
                            },
                        new Department
                            {
                                Code = 5,
                                Name = "Warehouse",
                                Employees = new List<Employee>
                                    {
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 5,
                                                Name = "Andy"
                                            },
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 2,
                                                Name = "Robert"
                                            },
                                        new Employee
                                            {
                                                Code = 6,
                                                Name = "Dave"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }

                    }
            };

        var organisations = new List<Organisation>
            {
                britishTelecomLtd,
                virginMediaLtd,
                pcWorldLtd,
                blueCatLtd
            };
```

Here I am adding the data to a dictionary:

```
   var legalEntitiesCollectionByType = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<Organisation>>
            {
                {
                    "Institutional", organisations
                        .Where(x => x.Type == "Institutional")
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ToList()
                },
                {
                    "Retail", organisations
                        .Where(x => x.Type == "Retail")
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                        .ToList()
                }
            };
```

doing it this way the sorting only happens at the Organisation level and not on the department or the employee level.

***My question is, how can I achieve sorting on all 3 levels within the object hierarchy while populating the dictionary above?***

Cheers

Comment: You sort when you query your dictionary, not when you populate it.

Comment: If it must happen in this method, then you need to recreate each object and sort the elements while doing this. For example:
`.OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name).Select(o => new Organisation() { //populate with data from o, using OrderBy when needed });`. However you should probably reconsider your design.

Comment: @ChrisHardie can't do that. The client needs a sorted dictionary.

Comment: @BartoszKP I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do all three levels of sorting inside the objects that you return, like this (I'll show only the `"Retail"`, the `"Institutional"` needs to be sorted in the same way):

```
{
"Retail", organisations
    .Where(x => x.Type == "Retail")
    .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new Organisation {
        x.Code
    ,   x.Type
    ,   x.Name
    ,   Departments = x.Departmentsd.OrderBy(d => d.Code).ThenBy(d => d.Name)
        .Select(d => new Department {
            d.Code
        ,   d.Name
        ,   Employees = d.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Code).ThenBy(e => e.Name).ToList()
        })
    }).ToList()
}
```

Since you need to select this multiple times, you may want to wrap this code in a method, and use it from several spots, like this:

```
private Organisation SortedOrganisation(Organisation x) {
    return new Organisation {
        x.Code
    ,   x.Type
    ,   x.Name
    ,   Departments = x.Departmentsd.OrderBy(d => d.Code).ThenBy(d => d.Name)
        .Select(d => new Department {
            d.Code
        ,   d.Name
        ,   Employees = d.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Code).ThenBy(e => e.Name).ToList()
        })
    };
}

...

var legalEntitiesCollectionByType = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<Organisation>>
        {
            {
                "Institutional", organisations
                    .Where(x => x.Type == "Institutional")
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select(SortedOrganisation)
                    .ToList()
            },
            {
                "Retail", organisations
                    .Where(x => x.Type == "Retail")
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select(SortedOrganisation)
                    .ToList()
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I am working on your suggested solution but will get back to you shortly. Cheers

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but there's a simpler way of achieving the same result:

```
organisations = organisations.OrderBy(org =>
{
   org.Departments = org.Departments
   .OrderBy(dept =>
   {
     dept.Employees = dept.Employees
                     .OrderBy(employee => employee.Code)
                     .ThenBy(employee=>employee.Name);
     return dept.Code;
   })
   .ThenBy(dept=>dept.Name);

   return org.Code;
})
.ThenBy(org=>org.Name);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion. There is a typo -- Departmets should be Departments and each of the "...ThenBy(...) needs to end with a .ToList();

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. As for the .ToList() I don't think it's really necessary. I'll check and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort before :

```
    organisations.ToList().ForEach(o => o.Departments = o.Departments.OrderBy(d => d.Code).ToList());
    organisations.SelectMany(o => o.Departments).ToList().ForEach(d => d.Employees = d.Employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToList());
```

And then use the list already sorted

```
        var legalEntitiesCollectionByType = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<Organisation>>
        {
            {
                "Institutional", organisations
                    .Where(x => x.Type == "Institutional")
                    .ToList()
            },
            {
                "Retail", organisations
                    .Where(x => x.Type == "Retail")
                    .ToList()
            }
        };
```

NB : the sort is not in place, you can achieve this using a `comparer`

```
        organisations.ToList().ForEach(o => o.Departments.Sort(CreateCustomComparison));
        organisations.SelectMany(o => o.Departments).ToList().ForEach(d => d.Employees.Sort(CreateCustomComparison));
```

Comment: why use comparer when you have all that functionality implemented within linq ? . Linq's orderby does the job pretty well.

Comment: Because 'orderby' does not order 'in place', it generates a new IEnumerable and I need to assign it. 'Sort' method, on the contrary, does the job 'in place'.

Comment: These guys are same something else http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378603/linq-orderby-vs-icomparer

Answer (score 2):

If `Employees` ever need to be sorted by code and name then you can make that property a [`SortedList<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).

```
public class Department
{
    ...
    public SortedList<Tuple<int, string>, Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Prior to .NET 4 you could use `KeyValuePair` instead of `Tuple`.

When creating `Employees` object you'd need to provide `IComparer` object for sorted list's key.

```
Employees = new SortedList<Tuple<int, string>, Employee>(new EmployeeKeyComparer());
```

where `EmployeeKeyComparer` could be defined as

```
public class EmployeeKeyComparer : IComparer<Tuple<int, string>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<int, string> x, Tuple<int, string> y)
    {
        if (x.First == y.First)
            return StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x.Second, y.Second);
        else
            return x.First.CompareTo(y.First);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but if i am using linq orderby i shouldnt have the need to implement an IComparer.

Comment: @HaroonEmmanuel, if the list is always required to be sorted then it makes sense to sort it only once, rather than sort it with linq every time it's used.

Answer (score -1):

```
var legalEntitiesCollectionByType = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<Organisation>>
            {
                {
                    "Institutional", organisations
                        .Where(x => x.Type == "Institutional")
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(o => new Organisation{Code = x.Code,Departaments = x.Departaments.OrderBy(c => c).ToList()  }).ToList()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please provide more information in your answer. Why does this code work better/different than the accepted answer?