# Sorting a nested list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a structure as follows:

```
class A {
    IEnumerable<B> BList {get;set;}
}

class B {
    IEnumerable<C> CList {get;set};
    int OrderId {get;set;}
}

class C {
    int OrderId {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to return a list of As where it's BList is ordered by it's OrderId and for each B in that list , 
it's CList is also ordered by it's OrderId.

These are models I use with EF6, and classes A,B,C correspond to db tables.

I have spent some trying to 'linq-ify' this, but without success. Is it doable?

EDIT: duplicate of [Sort a list and all its nested objects using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853573/sort-a-list-and-all-its-nested-objects-using-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, as nobody wanted to answer and you don't add more here is my take on it for now:

```
public static A SortEverything(A input)
{
    return new A
    {
        BList = 
            input.BList
            .Select(b =>
                new B
                {
                    OrderId = b.OrderId,
                    CList = b.CList.OrderBy(c => c.OrderId)
                })
            .OrderBy(b => b.OrderId)
    };
}
```

to return a so *sorted* list of `A`s having one input list/enumerable `IEnumerable<A> input` you just have to

```
var sorted = input.Select(SortEverything);
```

BTW: there are some issues in your classes - of course you have to make the properties public:

```
class A {
    public IEnumerable<B> BList {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public IEnumerable<C> CList {get; set; }
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
}

class C {
    public int OrderId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: BTW, would be nice to see why the question got downvoted. How am I otherwise gonna learn to write proper questions?

Comment: don't think to much about it - that's the way Stackoverflow works ATM - it's really bad in the big categories (like C++,Java,C#) - if you don't give a question where they can do a quick < 1min answer they will downvote you without any comment - ignore it and carry on