# Sorting a ListView by multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, sorting, listview

I have 3 columns in my `ListView`: name, `string` value and `int` value.

> Name:Item1, Item2, Item3
>
> string value:A, B, A
>
> int value:3,2,1

I want to sort my `ListView` first, by string value. Like this:

> Name:Item1, Item3, Item2
>
> string value:A, A, B
>
> int value:3,1,2

After that I want to sort by int value. Like this:

> Name:Item3, Item1, Item2
>
> string value:A, A, B
>
> int value:1,3,2

To do this should I use `List<>` or is there any way?
If I should use `List<>` what is the proper way to the it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` to sort the `letter`(string) and `number` (int) properties:

```
List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>()
{
    new myClass(){name="Item1",letter="A", number=3 },
    new myClass(){name="Item2",letter="B", number=2 },
    new myClass(){name="Item3",letter="A", number=1 }
};

var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x.letter).ThenBy(x => x.number).ToList();
```

**result:**

> name:Item3, Item1, Item2
>
> letter:A, A, B
>
> number:1,3,2

Add items from the list `result` to `ListView`:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("name");
listView1.Columns.Add("letter");
listView1.Columns.Add("number");
foreach (var item in result)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { item.name,item.letter,item.number.ToString()}));
}
```

`myClass`:

```
class myClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string letter { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
}
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l29IBl)

Comment: Probably I will use this method, but a question. What do you suggest? Using this or @Jimi 's method. This seems easy but I have no idea about performance.

Comment: The answers on this question :[LINQ_orderby_vs_IComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378603/linq-orderby-vs-icomparer) suggest to use my solution (LINQ OrderBy).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom [ListViewItemSorter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemsorter) to sort the columns of a ListView control.

This is an custom overloaded [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer) that lets you specify 1 or 2 columns for sorting, with the option to pass no parameters for a default `Column[0]` order.

Specify a sort order:

```
listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

...and the Indexes of the Columns you want to compare. The order in which you enter them is of course important. In you example you should enter:

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(1, 2);
```

The Default sorting Column[0] can be set like this:

```
listView1.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer();
```

The `ListViewItemComparer` Class:

```
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
{
    private int col1 = -1;
    private int col2 = -1;

    public ListViewItemComparer() => col1 = 0;
    public ListViewItemComparer(int Column) => col1 = Column;

    public ListViewItemComparer(int Column1, int Column2)
    {
        col1 = Column1;
        col2 = Column2;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int result = string.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col1].Text, 
           ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col1].Text);
        if (!(col2 < 0))
            result |= string.Compare(((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[col2].Text, 
           ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[col2].Text);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `IEnumerable<T>` like a `List<T>`

```
List<T> sortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2).ThenBy(x => x.Col3).ToList();
```